# Get unique values from MySql

Tags: mysql, distinct

In my table are values like: 14, 15, 14, R14, R15, R15C, R14C,....

With current distinct mode I get: 14, R14, R14C, R15, R15C,...

But what I want is only unique numbers like this: 14, 15,...

To get rid of letters and get unique numbers only?

My current code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT diameter FROM tires WHERE category = '$cat' ORDER BY diameter ASC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 0 + REGEXP_REPLACE(diameter, '^[[:alpha:]]*', '') diameter
FROM tires;
```

Regular expression removes all letter chars from the beginning, then the value is implicitly converted to numeric by adding zero (by fact - trailing letters are removed).

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ddf404e001cf6cc5ecc2ae7e999b6ca5)

---

> I forget to tell that I have decimal values like R22,5 - RoX

Replace comma with dot before or after REGEXP_REPLACE(), but before adding zero. For example,

```
SELECT DISTINCT 0 + REGEXP_REPLACE(REPLACE(diameter, ',', '.'), '^[[:alpha:]]*', '') diameter
FROM tires;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ce8b270db5fd22dfed31ee6eef5682e9)

PS. I'd recommend to add generated column to the table structure. See [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=31d4caacd011b1f2922d9caf42f8a076).

Comment: Amazing! It works like I want. I forget to tell that I have decimal values like R22,5 ... and with this output I get only 22 ... whole number. Is it possible to get with decimal?